# Could a person be convicted for violating the US Flag Code?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

If I understand the US Flag Code correctly, it is a federal law which prohibits certain actions, but does not allow any penalty for violations. Could a person technically be convicted under the Flag Code, as long as there was no penalty?

Comment: There is no prohibition in the US Flag Code so of course there is no penalty. "Should" is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

The Flag Code is not a criminal law, so the government is not permitted to bring criminal prosecution for violating it, and it therefore cannot secure a proper conviction for such a violation.

Comment: So it basically means "please don't do this, but we won't/can't do anything if you do"?

Comment: Burning the US flag is [protected speech](https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/491/397) as decided by SCOTUS.

Comment: @Someone That's correct.

Comment: @Someone: Other rules, governmental or otherwise, may explicitly or implicitly incorporate the Flag Code by reference.  If, for example, a business with many flags on its property has someone who is in charge of flying, storing, and otherwise maintaining them, that person would be expected to behave in conformance with the Flag Code absent any instructions to the contary.